# How to I correctly handle a FollowHyperlink Error in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

We're currently transitioning our current product site to a new one, and I need to put in some error handling to say that if the hyperlink returns an error on the new site, to look for it on the old site. The problem I'm having is that I'm currently trying to open up 2 separate pages. The logic would be:

1. If there's an error looking up [OldSKU] on the new site, follow the
   hyperlink to the old site for the [OldSKU]
2. If there's an error looking up [ClosestSKU] on the new site, follow the
   hyperlink to the old site for the [ClosestSKU]

In either case, only 2 tabs would open in the user's browser. With my current VBA, it's actually opening up 3 tabs, and I don't think my logic is sound.

```
Private Sub ClosestSKU_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    On Error GoTo Error_Old
    Access.FollowHyperlink "https://www.oursite.com/newstorefront/c/p/" & [OldSKU], , True
Error_Old:
    Access.FollowHyperlink "https://www.oursite.com/oldstorefront/search/?text=" & [OldSKU], , True

    On Error GoTo Error_New
    Access.FollowHyperlink "https://www.oursite.com/newstorefront/c/p/" & [ClosestSKU], , True
Error_New:
    Access.FollowHyperlink "https://www.oursite.com/oldstorefront/search/?text=" & [ClosestSKU], , True

End Sub
```

Any help/advice you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make sure your error handlers are out of the flow of your program. There are various ways to do that. If you don't want to move them, you can wrap them in `If False Then` to make sure they only get triggered if an error occurs.

```
Private Sub ClosestSKU_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    On Error GoTo Error_Old
    Access.FollowHyperlink "https://www.oursite.com/newstorefront/c/p/" & [OldSKU], , True
    If False Then
 Error_Old:
        Access.FollowHyperlink "https://www.oursite.com/oldstorefront/search/?text=" & [OldSKU], , True
    End If
    On Error GoTo Error_New
    Access.FollowHyperlink "https://www.oursite.com/newstorefront/c/p/" & [ClosestSKU], , True
    If False Then
Error_New:
        Access.FollowHyperlink "https://www.oursite.com/oldstorefront/search/?text=" & [ClosestSKU], , True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: perfection. Thanks for helping me understand that. I really appreciate it.